# How to get a list of objects

Tags: php, class, oop

I have the below class for a book. At the moment it has one method to retrieve a book from the database by ID. Obviously other methods could be added to delete a book, save a new book, etc.

```
class Book {

Public $id
public $name;
public $price;
public $isbn;

public function getBook($id) {

    $sql = 'SELECT id, name, price, isbn FROM book WHERE id = ' . (int) $id;

    $row = /* DB functions here to get a matching row */

    $this->name = $row['name'];
    $this->price = $row['price'];
    $this->isbn = $row['isbn'];
    return TRUE;
}
}
```

Here's my question, and something I've never been able to get to the bottom of. How do I get a list of all books, or all books beginning with the letter "A"?

To clarify I know how to query the database and loop through a result set. A constructor could be added in the above class to create a single book instance from each result. But where should my "searchBooks" method go? Should it be part of the Book class? Or should the search method be part of a completely different class, one called BookShop perhaps?

I hope I have explained this properly. I see so many examples where objects are dealt with on a singular basis but I cannot fathom how and where a list or collection of objects should be created.

Comment: Your example basically violates the single responsibility principle. In a nutshell: You'd have your model (`Book`) and a class responsible for accessing the database (`BookRepository`) where you could have functions querying for book titles, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> How do I get a list of all books, or all books beginning with the
>   letter "A"?

All books: `SELECT id, name, price, isbn FROM book`

All books that start with A:

`SELECT id, name, price, isbn FROM book WHERE name LIKE 'A%'`

OR:

`SELECT id, name, price, isbn FROM book WHERE SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1) = 'A'`

As to where the methods would go, look up "Repository" - a book shouldn't create itself.